# external monitor not properly detected

Tags: 14.04, intel, external-monitor

I am having a strange problem with my external monitor. I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) on hp elitebook 840 g1. I connected my laptop to an external monitor which has full HD option. Everything was working fine. Then suddenly the power to my external monitor got disconnected and I switched the display to the laptop (using <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>).

After that I have not been able to get the display to the external monitor. In fact when I try to boot my laptop with the external monitor being connected, the external monitor briefly displays the contents. The external monitor shows the display till I login. But once I have logged in, the external monitor goes blank.

So after logging in, the system is not able to identify the external monitor. In fact, when I click on displays in the system settings, it only shows the `"Built-in Display"` of the laptop.

It seems that once I have switched to the laptop display, the external monitor is not being recognized at all.

For clarity, I am showing you the output of `lshw -C video`:

```
$ sudo lshw -C video   *-display               
      description: VGA compatible controller
      product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 2
      bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
      version: 09
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
      configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
      resources: irq:65 memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

Comment: I found a temporary fix for this problem. I deleted ~/.config/monitor.xml file and restarted. Everything is properly displayed on the external monitor now.

But this is just a temporary fix. If I switch the display back to the laptop using (Fn + F4) commands, I again have the same problem. The system then stops detecting the external monitor. So I can not again switch to it :-(!

Comment: Looks like that's what I need to do. How do I do that exactly? (New to Ubuntu) :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the same laptop, and I "fixed" it by turning on the laptop with the monitor unplugged, and then plug in the monitor once logged in only.

Answer (score 0):

This bug seems to occur only for the VGA port. Display port works well, which may be used as workaround.

Verified on the same hardware and ubuntu (EliteBook 840, Ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie, and encountered the same problem of not being able to detect the monitor. I could not see the external monitor after an uninstallation of some packages. I tried deleting the monitor.xml file to no avail.
As I suspect the uninstallation may have deleted some files, I checked the installed display driver and I did not see the nvidia-331 that used to be installed. So, I re-install the NVIDIA display driver, and all is back again.

Comment: Also a newbie - how did you get to the monitor.xml file? Thanks

Comment: @bukko ~/.config/monitors.xml